# Convert a callback into a reactive publisher (Flux)

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I'm using a third party library to register a MessageListener, and when certain events occur they call registered listeners onMessage method

```
public interface MessageListener {  
   // third party code, it auto-scans for all MessageListeners and registers them
    void onMessage(Message message);
}


public class SimpleMessageListener implements MessageListener {
   public void onMessage(Message message) {
      //do something non blocking
      //is it possible to 'transmit' to messagePublisher
}
   public Flux<Message> messagePublisher() {
       // a method to which to subscribeOn    
   }
}
```

So my question is what is the best approach to turn this into a Flux

at the end I'd like to be able to do something like this

```
messagePublisher().subscribe(System.out::println);
```

************** edit
My first attempt is something like this

```
private List<FluxSink<Message>> handlers = new ArrayList<>();
public void onMessage(Message message) {
   handlers.forEach(han -> han.next(message));
}
public Flux<Message> messagePublisher() {
        return Flux.create(sink -> {
            handlers.add(sink);
            sink.onDispose(() -> handlers.remove(sink));
        });
    }
```

which works - but I feel like it's not a great solution, is it better to have the class implement FluxSink, and manually handle - currently I don't expect to have many subscribers. 
But many MessageListeners (one for each type)

Comment: you can add your edit as an answer and accept it, because that's the best solution IMO. Implementing `FluxSink` won't help, as it is not a `Flux`. Plus you need one sink per subscriber, to keep track of subscriber request.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a single `Flux` instance that bridges the messages observed by the `MessageListener`, e.g.

```java
public class SimpleMessageListener implements MessageListener {
   private FluxSink<Message> handler;
   private Flux<Message> flux;

   public SimpleMessageListener() {
      flux = Flux.create(emitter -> {
          handler = emitter;
      }, OverflowStrategy.DROP); // or some other overflow strategy
   }

   public void onMessage(Message message) {
       if (handler != null) {
           /* 
            * null check is required to avoid NPE if a message is received 
            * before any subscription occurs since handler is instantiated
            * lazily when the first subscription is requested
            */
           handler.next(message);
       }
   }

   public Flux<Message> messagePublisher() {
       return flux;
   }
}
```

Now all listeners can subscribe on the same `messsagePublisher()` `Flux` instance using Flux' [publish()](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#publish--) method and its returned [ConnectableFlux](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/ConnectableFlux.html):

```java
// fetch message publisher
Flux<Message> messagePublisher = messageListener.messagePublisher();

// prepare ConenctableFlux
ConnectableFlux<Message> connectableFlux = messagePublisher().publish();

// register subscribers
connectableFlux.subscribe(/* aConsumer */);
connectableFlux.subscribe(/* aCoreSubscriber */);
connectableFlux.subscribe(/* aSubscriber */);

// connect the ConnectableFlux to messagePublisher
connectableFlux.connect();
```